# Memory usage for map from an to elements of strictly increasing values

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashmap

**Data structure and usage of the map `M`**

In my code, I have a map called `M` defined as

```
class T
{
public:
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
    size_t c;
    size_t d;
    size_t e;
    size_t f;

    size_t sum()
    {
        return a+b+c+d+e+f;
    }
}

const std::vector<T> M;
```

`M` is a `const`. It is build at the beginning of a long process and it is then only used to read matching between the index `i` and the values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`. For example

```
auto& c = M[i].c;
```

**Properties of the map**

The first element of the map always has a `sum` of 1. For each of the following element, always, one and only one of the 6 attributes (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` or `f`) has its value increased by exactly 1. In other words, the following assertions about the map are always true

```
if (i < M.size())
{
   if (i >= 0)
       assert(M[i].sum() == i+1);

   if (i > 0)
   {          
       assert(M[i].sum() - M[i-1].sum() == 1);
       assert(M[i].a == M[i-1].a || M[i].a == M[i-1].a + 1);
       assert(M[i].b == M[i-1].b || M[i].b == M[i-1].b + 1);
       assert(M[i].c == M[i-1].c || M[i].c == M[i-1].c + 1);
       assert(M[i].d == M[i-1].d || M[i].d == M[i-1].d + 1);
       assert(M[i].e == M[i-1].e || M[i].e == M[i-1].e + 1);
       assert(M[i].f == M[i-1].f || M[i].f == M[i-1].f + 1);
   }
}
```

**Issue and question**

This system worked well until recently because I now need `M` to be 5e8 in length, which end up taking up a lot of unnecessary RAM.

Is there a way I could create a map that allows for constant time access to the matching between `i` and either `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` or `f` without taking up so much RAM?

Comment: How big is `size_t` on your system, 4 or 8 bytes?  `M` would "only" be 12 or 24GB, and if you use `.reserve` on the vector you construct to initialize `M` that should minimize the extra memory required.  There are some near constant time access methods that can reduce the memory required (mostly constant time plus a little extra). Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I use reserve. It is still too much RAM usage as it consumes almost half the RAM usage of the entire process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the previous value, it is enough information to know which of the variables increased by one. As there are six of them (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`), you can represent that information with 3 bits. For `n`-entries, you will need 3 * `n` bits in total.

In terms of size, that is an improvement, but it will violate your constant-access constraint, as you need to iterate over all previous entries for each lookup. But you can trade off, speed vs memory but storing snapshots. For example, if you keep snapshots after 100 elements, you will in the worst case have to iterate over the last 100 entries. That is still `O(1)`.

You would need to tune the step size of the snapshots, but as long as you use a constant number, you will have `O(1)` lookup.